# DRY approach to Razor syntax marking the currently viewed tab of a web page

Tags: razor, dry

I have some tabs at the top of a web page: home, features, contact, etc.

I need the category I am currently on to be marked as .

How can I appropriately code my _Layout.cshtml page with razor syntax so that I don't have to manually mark each page's appropriate tab as class="current" ?

```
<li class="current">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Blog", "Blog", "Home")
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Portfolio", "Portfolio", "Home")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example way you could do it.

```
@helper BuildLink(string name, string action, string controller)
{
    var url = Url.Action(action, controller);
    bool isActive = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Equals(url, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    <li class="@(isActive ? "current" : String.Empty)"><a href="@(url)">@name</a></li>
}

@BuildLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
@BuildLink("Blog", "Blog", "Home")
@BuildLink("Portfolio", "Portfolio", "Home")
```

Comment: Seems like a good plan, but I'm getting this error: CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context - in reference to var url = Url.Action(action, controller);

Comment: That's odd, I'd say maybe you weren't referencing System.Web.MVC, but Html.ActionLink already requires that. Does your master page inherit System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage? (look in your config file)

Comment: The word Master isn't in my project at all - so I'm guessing not.  I added this line to my namespaces section on the config: <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage"/> - did not help, I'm guessing I did that wrong.  Also, until now, I have made zero changes to the Web.config since generating the app.

Comment: Maybe it has to do that my HTMLHelpers.cshtml file containing the above helper is under App_Code ?

Comment: It would be a line like "<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">" located in the web.config of your View folder. If you are missing it. Try adding it, saving, then reloading the solution (although, it should be included by default...)

Comment: I put the helper within the _Layout.cshtml page instead of in a folder in App_Code and the Url thing worked.  Everything works that way - I made it too complicated by putting it with my other helpers in the App_Code folder.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can set on each controller ViewData["Home"] = "activeTab" class, and use that information in the view.

This will make the tab active if the value of that viewData dictionary is taken.
Is simple and very clean.

Inside controller set viewdata like this

```
ViewData["SomeTab"] = "activeTab";
    return View("Index");
```

View side:

```
<li class="<@ ((string)ViewData["SomeTab"] ?? "") >"><@Html.ActionLink("SomeTab", "Index", "Home")></li>
<li class="<@ ((string)ViewData["MyPage"] ?? "") %>"><@Html.ActionLink("MyPage", "MyPage", "")></li>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking more for a solution that avoided the controller altogether.